# Differences between empty and blank lines in regexps

Tags: regex, perl, posix

There are already several [good discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127384/what-is-a-regex-to-match-only-an-empty-string/36161782#36161782) of [regular expressions and empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618634/matching-an-empty-string-with-regex) on SO. I'll remove this question if it is a duplicate.

Can anyone explain why this script outputs `5 3 4 5 4 3` instead of `4 3 4 4 4 3`? When I run it in the debugger `$blank` and `$classyblank` stay at "4" (which I assume is the correct value) until the just before the print statement.

```
my ( $blank, $nonblank, $non_nonblank, 
     $classyblank,  $classyspace, $blanketyblank ) = 0 ;

while (<DATA>) {

  $blank++ if /\p{IsBlank}/         ; # POSIXly blank - 4?
  $nonblank++ if /^\P{IsBlank}$/    ; # POSIXly non-blank - 3
  $non_nonblank++ if not /\S/       ; # perlishly not non-blank - 4
  $classyblank++ if /[[:blank:]]/   ; # older(?) charclass blankness - 4?
  $classyspace++ if /^[[:space:]]$/ ; # older(?) charclass whitespace - 4
  $blanketyblank++ if /^$/          ; # perlishly *really empty*  - 3

}

print join " ", $blank, $nonblank, $non_nonblank,
            $classyblank, $classyspace, $blanketyblank , "\n" ;

__DATA__

line above only has a linefeed this one is not blank because: words

this line is followed by a line with white space (you may need to add it)

then another blank line following this one

THE END :-\
```

Is it something to do with the `__DATA__` section or am I misunderstanding POSIX regular expressions?

---

**ps:**

As noted in  comment on a timely post [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36129515/2019415), "really empty" (`/^$/`) can miss non-emptiness:

```
perl -E 'my $string = "\n" . "foo\n\n" ; say "empty" if $string =~ /^$/ ;'
perl -E 'my $string = "\n" . "bar\n\n" ; say "empty" if $string =~ /\A\z/ ;'
perl -E 'my $string = "\n" . "baz\n\n" ; say "empty" if $string =~ /\S/ ;'
```

Comment: Then there's `if /\A\Z/ ` and `if /\A\z/ ` ... which are pretty consistent across different languages [except python but that's OK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063420/perl-compatible-regular-expression-pcre-in-python).

Comment: `This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for amd64-freebsd`

Comment: Not related to your core question, but `my $string = "\n", "foo\n\n"` assigns a single newline to `$string`. The rest is thrown away because of the comma operator.

Comment: I addressed this at length in [my answer to your recent comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128040/extract-and-filter-a-range-of-lines-from-the-input-using-perl/36129515?noredirect=1#comment59963005_36129515) I won't write it up again to match your newly-phrased question. The only delinquent in the patterns you have used is `$`, which will match the end of a string or before the newline of it is the last character. `\p{IsBlank}`, `[[:blank:]]` are simple character classes and you can check what they do from [perldoc perluniprops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html)

Comment: @Borodin - thanks.  I'm trying to get straightened out about the character classes from the charts in [`perlrecharclass`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) by lining them up with well their known perl equivalents (such as `/\S/`) and/or related "idioms". I was getting results I couldn't explain: specifically how `\v`, \s' and `\h` interact with  `\n` and `" "`. I think I have it figured out now and will add a separate answer if one doesn't appear.

Comment: @thissuitisnotblack typo ... I think.  Still not sure if correction illustrates the need to approach non-emptiness carefully à la borodin

Comment: *i.e.* carefully à la @borodin

Comment: @G.Cito: I don't understand what issue you have. Your main mistake is to expect any character class to identify whether a line is "empty" or "blank". I suggest you open anew question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\p{IsBlank}/` doesn't check for a empty string. `\p` matches a character that has the specified Unicode property.

```
$ unichars '\p{IsBlank}' | cat
 ---- U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
 ---- U+0020 SPACE
 ---- U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
 ---- U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
 ---- U+2000 EN QUAD
 ---- U+2001 EM QUAD
 ---- U+2002 EN SPACE
 ---- U+2003 EM SPACE
 ---- U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2007 FIGURE SPACE
 ---- U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
 ---- U+2009 THIN SPACE
 ---- U+200A HAIR SPACE
 ---- U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
 ---- U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
 ---- U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

It matches `" \n"` since SPACE has the IsBlank property.

---

`/[[:blank:]]/` doesn't check for a empty string. `[...]` matches a character that is a member of the specified class.

```
$ unichars '[[:blank:]]' | cat
 ---- U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION
 ---- U+0020 SPACE
 ---- U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
 ---- U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
 ---- U+2000 EN QUAD
 ---- U+2001 EM QUAD
 ---- U+2002 EN SPACE
 ---- U+2003 EM SPACE
 ---- U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
 ---- U+2007 FIGURE SPACE
 ---- U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
 ---- U+2009 THIN SPACE
 ---- U+200A HAIR SPACE
 ---- U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
 ---- U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
 ---- U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

It matches `" \n"` since SPACE is a member of the `[:blank:]` POSIX character class and thus a member of the `[[:blank:]]` character class.

Comment: Thanks, beginning to grok ... since `$nonblank++ if /\P{IsBlank}/` (without the anchors) gives me "8" (`__DATA__` has 8 lines) I assume it is counting `\n` as non-`{IsBlank}` (due to `\P`) and thus is seeing 8 matches. Then, as `/^\P{IsBlank}$/`, incrementing is based on the three lines of single non-blank horizontal characters (`\n`) so I get "3".  However `/\p{IsBlank}` gives me a count of "5" because there are five rows with `\s` style horizontal "blank characters": the four with text (and whitespace between words), and line number 5 which consists of `" "\n` appearing as an empty row.